# QML - Imported JS object not notifiable

Tags: javascript, qml

I've made a JS file with objects:

```
myObject {
    myVar: "hello"
}
```

That I then import in QML:

```
import "myObject.js" as SomeObjects
Rectangle {
    Text {
        color: "red"
        text: SomeObjects.myObject.myVar        
    }
}
```

But if I do `SomeObjects.myObject.myVar = "goodbye"` the Text Component in QML will not be updated. So this must mean that JS objects are not notifiable.

What is the best way to store notifiable variables in an imported file with QML?

Comment: Put QtObject in a separate *.qml file. Later you can create one instance in root qml file and easily access it from all other parts of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript objects don't have such feature like property binding. So the only way is to use QML object. If you have any calculation in JS you can put it in different js file.

```
import "myObject.js" as SomeObjects

QtObject {
    id: myObject
    property string myVar: ""
    function someCalculation () {
        SomeObjects.somefunction(myVar);
    }
}

Text {
    text: myObject.myVar
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    myObject.myVar = "Hello"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to put all my notifiable variables in an external file because there are a lot of them and I don't want a big overhead in my main QML file.

Comment: Why do you think that putting your data in JS instead of QML will be faster?

Comment: Not faster, just more esthetic. I'm building an Open Source Video Player UI, so I'm trying to keep all main components of the player (toolbar, playlist menu, etc) and skinning variables separate for an easier understanding of themes and skinning.

https://github.com/jaruba/WebChimeraPlayer/tree/master/player

Comment: And the variables that I need to be notifiable are in this file:
https://github.com/jaruba/WebChimeraPlayer/blob/master/player/themes/sleek/ui-settings.js
I don't really want all those variables in the header of my main QML file..

Comment: Just put the object in a separate non-visual `Item` included in the `main.qml` if you don't want to "pollute" the latter. Otherwise define a back-end c++ object which is registered as a type or added as a context property.

Comment: `QtObject` is good for this, `Item` more suitable vfor visual items. But as @BaCaRoZzo said use C++ object if you want you object will be really fast